# Prove that hexagonal closed packing(HCP) and face centred cubic(FCC) are the most closely packed structures

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

I was going through the packing fractions for different crystal structures. I know that how to calculate the packing fractions of bcc(0.62), hcp(0.74), fcp(0.74). But what is the proof that we can not get packing fraction greater than packing fraction of hcp and fcc in any other arrangement of crystals in 3d closed packing.

Comment: Check out the Kepler Conjecture. It was only recently proven with the use of computers.

Comment: Thanks for help..